# Magento installation on local host

Tags: php, magento

I want to do a project in my local host. How can I install Magento on my PHP Apache local server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, a simple solution would be to use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), which is basically a pre-packaged installation of Apache, PHP, MySQL plus additional useful tools. You might give it a try :)

If you're using Linux, a Google search for "LAMP tutorial" should yield some results useful to you..

Happy hacking! :)

Edit: Okay, maybe because it's early in the morning here, I seem to have misunderstood your question. Maybe you can find some further information regarding the Magento installation in the [Installation guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-installation-guide). If you could describe your trouble a little more detailed, we could help too.

Answer (score 2):

Need more detail on what stage you're stuck at.

Even so - there's a catch in Magento.  It doesn't like to be installed on 'localhost'.  Best to put your hostname as '127.0.0.1', which is a synonym for localhost.